# Angular Route, 1 Application, 2 different folders

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, base-tag

Is the following scenario possible? I have the same application on two URLs:

- url.tld/topicA/#main
- url.tld/topicA/#foo/:bar
- url.tld/topicB/#:foo

I tried to define the route with the `<base />` tag but my code run in endless redirects :(

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: the how to is the question

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue?